# HTML/CSS: IE8 padding / background-position problems

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer, cross-browser

For the live view of the problem page go here: http://rcnhca.org.uk/sites/first_steps/health-safety-and-security/

**Problem 1:**     If you go to that link and rollover the dropdown navigation and it's children you will notice I animate a star background image across each `li` on `mouseenter`. However the first time you roll over it in IE8 it animates from the middle of the `li` even though I specified `background-position: -25px 50%;`, the strange thing is once jquery applies the same settings inline, it starts to work as expected.

**Problem 2:**     As you can see in the image below, IE8 **(This works correctly in IE7)** is incorrectly rendering my padding. I have reset all margin and padding using `* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}` in [core.css](http://rcnhca.org.uk/sites/first_steps/wp-content/themes/Mega%20Amazing/library/css/core.css) :

[image: padding error]

The HTML markup for this navigation bar is:

```
<header class="one">
    <nav class="container_16 clearfix" id="breadcrumbs">
        <a href="http://rcnhca.org.uk/sites/first_steps" id="home"></a>
        <ul id="parent">
            <li>
                <a href="http://rcnhca.org.uk/sites/first_steps/communication/">Communication</a>
                <ul class="child">
                    <li><a href="http://rcnhca.org.uk/sites/first_steps/getting-started/">Getting started</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://rcnhca.org.uk/sites/first_steps/health-safety-and-security/">Health, Safety and Security</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://rcnhca.org.uk/sites/first_steps/personal-and-people-development/">Personal and people development </a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://rcnhca.org.uk/sites/first_steps/quality/">Quality</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://rcnhca.org.uk/sites/first_steps/equality-diversity-and-rights/">Equality, diversity and rights </a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://rcnhca.org.uk/sites/first_steps/clinical-skills/">Clinical skills</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://rcnhca.org.uk/sites/first_steps/additional-material/">Additional material</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Select a topic</a>
                <ul class="child">
                    <li><a href="http://rcnhca.org.uk/sites/first_steps/communication/why-communication-is-important/">Why communication is important</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://rcnhca.org.uk/sites/first_steps/communication/communication-methods/">Communication methods</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://rcnhca.org.uk/sites/first_steps/communication/written-communication/">Barriers to communication</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

and the CSS to boot:

```
header {
    width: 100%;
}

header.one {
    height: 50px;
    background: #44a9c4;
}

header.two {
    height: 45px;
    background: #3393b5;
}


/* =============================================================================
   Breadcrumb navigation
   ========================================================================== */

#breadcrumbs {
    padding: 0 3px 3px 0;
    background: #ffffff;
    border: 0px solid;
    border-left: #3a90a7 2px solid;
    border-right: #3a90a7 2px solid;
    border-bottom: #3a90a7 2px solid;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

#breadcrumbs #home{
    display: block;
    height: 39px;
    width: 55px;
    float: left;
    background-image: url(library/images/home_icon.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;    
    text-indent: -999em;
}

#breadcrumbs ul#parent {
    height: 39px;
    width: 905px;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    background: #f38630;
    border: 0px solid;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px -2px 0px 0px #cf7229;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px -2px 0px 0px #cf7229;
    box-shadow: inset 0px -2px 0px 0px #cf7229;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

#breadcrumbs ul#parent li {
    position: relative;
    height: 39px;
    float: left;
    min-width: 1px; /* required to fix Opera bug */
    padding: 0 47px 0 15px;
    background-image: url(library/images/breadcrumb_seperator.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
    line-height: 39px;
}

#breadcrumbs ul#parent li a {
    display: block;
    height: 42px;
    font-size: 0.938em;
    font-weight:900;
    letter-spacing: 0.01em;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0px 2px 0px #cf7229;
}

#breadcrumbs ul li a:visited {
    color: #ffffff;
}
#breadcrumbs ul#parent li:first-child ul {
    left: -5px;
}
#breadcrumbs ul#parent li ul {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    left: -28px;
    top: 42px;
    background: #ffffff;
    border-left: #3a90a7 2px solid;
    border-right: #3a90a7 2px solid;
    border-bottom: #3a90a7 2px solid;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

.js #breadcrumbs ul#parent li ul {
    display:none;
}

.no-js #breadcrumbs ul#parent li ul {
    left: -999em;
}

#breadcrumbs ul#parent li ul li {
    float: none;
    height: 26px;
    margin: 0 3px 3px 3px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    background-image: url(library/images/star-icon.png);
    background-position: -25px center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: #738793;
    border-radius: 5px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 5px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    line-height: 26px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#breadcrumbs ul#parent li ul li a{
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: none;
    letter-spacing: 0.01em;
    font-weight: 100;
}

#breadcrumbs ul#parent li ul li:hover{
    background-color: #3393b5;
}

.no-js #breadcrumbs ul#parent li ul li:hover{
    background-position: 6px center;
    text-indent: 10px;
}

#breadcrumbs ul#parent li:hover ul {
    z-index: 2;
}

.no-js #breadcrumbs ul#parent li:hover ul {
    left: -5px;
}
```

I have spent ages trying to debug this problem and can't work out why this is happening, if anyone can shine some light on the matter it would be great. (Note: I am using [HTML5SHIV](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) to render HTML5 elements in legacy browsers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have an answer to what the bug is or why IE8 is acting that way but I managed to overcome the margin issue by removing the floats from `#home` and `ul#parent` and absolutely positioning them relative to `#breadcrumbs` and giving it an explicit height like so:

```
#breadcrumbs {
    height: 39px;
    padding: 0 3px 3px 0;
    background: #ffffff;
    position: relative;
    border: 0px solid;
    border-left: #3a90a7 2px solid;
    border-right: #3a90a7 2px solid;
    border-bottom: #3a90a7 2px solid;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

#breadcrumbs #home{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 39px;
    width: 55px;
    float: left;
    background-image: url(library/images/home_icon.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;    
    text-indent: -999em;
}

#breadcrumbs ul#parent {
    height: 39px;
    width: 885px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 3px;
    top: 0px;
    background: #f38630;
    margin: 0px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px -2px 0px 0px #cf7229;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px -2px 0px 0px #cf7229;
    box-shadow: inset 0px -2px 0px 0px #cf7229;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
```

For the issue with the background image I made a jquery function to add the background position to the elements inline after they have loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Using `HTML5Shiv` has it's loads of problems in IE 7-8. If the html5 tags are `position:static` (browser default), it seems like IE sometimes fails to redraw those elements when something is animated/moved inside using javascript. Most of the time, if you are able to put a `position:relative` on those tags problems disappear as IE seems to trigger `hasLayout` correctly on relatively positioned elements.